# verbatim and overlays

Tags: beamer, verbatim, overlays

I am trying to display a `verbatim` environment in an overlay. I have the following code but it is giving errors:

```
\only<2->{
\begin{verbatim}
Select T3.Subject
From  T as T1, T as T2, T as T3
Where T1.Predict=“BornOnDate” and
T1.Object=“1809-02-12” and 
T2.Predict=“DiedOnDate” and 
T2.Object=“1865-04-15” and 
T3. Predict=“hasName” and 
T1.Subject = T2.Subject and 
T2. Subject= T3.subject 
\end{verbatim}
}
```

Could anyone point what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Which table do you mean? To use overlay specification in beamer you need the `semiverbatim` environment.

Comment: You are talking about a `tabular`, but your code shows `verbatim`. What is it now?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Verbatim material isn't allowed in macro argument, because the full argument is read before `verbatim` is processed. By then all text is already converted internally, i.e. all `\abcd` are already macros, all `%text` is already stripped etc.

Because `frame` is actually a pseudo-environment which reads its content like a macro you need to use its `fragile` option to take special care for verbatim and similar content. However, you are still not allowed to use it inside a macro's argument. I would store it in a box register and use that inside `\only`. For some reason this doesn't work with the `verbatim` environment but well with `lstlisting` from the `listing` package. You can and should also box the material outside of a `frame`, then you don't need the `fragile` option.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newsavebox{\mysavebox}
\usepackage{listings}


\begin{document}

\begin{lrbox}{\mysavebox}
\begin{lstlisting}
Select T3.Subject
From  T as T1, T as T2, T as T3
Where T1.Predict="BornOnDate" and 
T1.Object="1809-02-12" and
T2.Predict="DiedOnDate" and
T2.Object="1865-04-15" and 
T3. Predict="hasName" and
T1.Subject = T2.Subject and 
T2. Subject= T3.subject
\end{lstlisting}
\end{lrbox}

\begin{frame}{Some title}
\only<2->{\usebox{\mysavebox}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just to note that this also seems to center the listing (which is good considering all the issues with centering them).

Answer (score 11):

`verbatim` is only possible with the macro `\defverbatim`. However, instead of `verbatim` you should use the package `listings`. Can be done in the same way. If you need it colored then use `\defverbatim[colored]{...}`

```
\documentclass{beamer}      
\begin{document}

\defverbatim{\foo}{%
\begin{verbatim}
Select T3.Subject
From  T as T1, T as T2, T as T3
Where T1.Predict=“BornOnDate” and 
T1.Object=“1809-02-12” and
T2.Predict=“DiedOnDate” and
T2.Object=“1865-04-15” and 
T3. Predict=“hasName” and
T1.Subject = T2.Subject and 
T2. Subject= T3.subject
\end{verbatim}
}

\begin{frame}{Some title}
\only<2->{\foo}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the `onlyenv` environment instead of the `\only` command can help here, as pointed out at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/274725/15107.