# Center listing horizontally in Beamer

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, listings

I am trying to simply center a listing typeset with `listings` in a Beamer slide.
There is some strange behaviour I cannot understand.

I have been testing 3 methods of centering:

- the `center` environment
- the `\centering` command
- the `centering` environment

None of these produce a centered listing.

Additionally, using the `center` environment causes the listing to contain an extra small vertical space just before the first code line.

If I wrap the listing in a `tikz` node, all the methods work, although the extra vertical space with `center` remains.
I cannot wrap the listing with a `\makebox` because it messes with the parsing.

The question is: **Why is this happening and how can I fix it?**

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}

\begin{document}

% REGULAR, EXPECTED BEHAVIOUR
\begin{frame}[fragile]{No centering}
  \begin{lstlisting}[gobble=4]
    hello := "world";
    there := 1;
  \end{lstlisting}
  \par Bla\par
\end{frame}

% NO CENTERING ACHIEVED, STRANGE EXTRA VERTICAL SPACE
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Center Env}
\begin{center}%
  \begin{lstlisting}[gobble=4]
    hello := "world";
    there := 1;
  \end{lstlisting}%
  \par Bla\par
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Centering}
  \centering%
  \begin{lstlisting}[gobble=4]
    hello := "world";
    there := 1;
  \end{lstlisting}
  \par Bla\par
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Centering Env}
  \begin{centering}%
  \begin{lstlisting}[gobble=4]
    hello := "world";
    there := 1;
  \end{lstlisting}
  \par Bla\par
  \end{centering}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Center Env + Tikz node}
  \begin{center}%
  \tikz\node{%
  \begin{lstlisting}[gobble=4]
    hello := "world";
    there := 1;
  \end{lstlisting}
  };
  \par Bla\par
  \end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Centering + Tikz node}
  \centering%
  \tikz\node{%
  \begin{lstlisting}[gobble=4]
    hello := "world";
    there := 1;
  \end{lstlisting}
  };
  \par Bla\par
\end{frame}

%%% GENERATES AN ERROR
% \begin{frame}[fragile]{Error}
%   \begin{center}%
%   \makebox{%
%   \begin{lstlisting}[gobble=4]
%     hello := "world";
%     there := 1;
%   \end{lstlisting}%
%   }
%   \end{center}
% \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

**EDIT**

Thanks to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32488/36686) I worked out a solution with saveboxes:

```
\newsavebox{\codebox}
\begin{lrbox}{\codebox}
  \begin{lstlisting}[gobble=4]
    hello := "world";
    there := 1;
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{lrbox}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Centering}
  \centering%
  \usebox{\codebox}
  \par Bla\par
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Centering Env}
  \begin{centering}%
  \usebox{\codebox}
  \par Bla\par
  \end{centering}
\end{frame}
```

The question remains: Why is this happening (the extra vspace is especially mysterious) and is there a better way?

Comment: `\leavevmode\hbox{...}` works as well.  Beamer does funny things with centering.  If takes two `\hfil`s to center left justified text.

Comment: I now get why `\leavevmode\hbox{...}` works: it's not Beamer's fault, it's `listings` who only boxes the listing if in horizontal mode!

Comment: The \hbox is for listings, but the \leavevmode is for beamer.

Answer (score 6):

Workaround:

If you artificially make the linewidth smaller (e.g. by wrapping the listing in a minipage), the whole listing can be centred, however the text will still be left aligned with respect to the minipage.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[fragile]{No centering}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{.381\textwidth}
  \begin{lstlisting}[gobble=4]
    hello := "world";
    there := 1;
  \end{lstlisting}
    \end{minipage}
  \par Bla\par
\end{frame}




\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think that's the case: the tikz node is correctly sized, and the lrbox method also does not need an explicit width...

Comment: Also, the same centering methods in the `article` class work with `listings`

Comment: AH! This [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/245750/36686) explains what happens:
> The lstlisting package only boxes the contents if it starts in horizontal mode